# How to use searchsorted on a column of a multidimensional array in Julia?

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia

I have a sorted two-dimensional array like this:

```
testv = sortrows(["zebra" "N" 20; "jimi" "V" 100; "johnny" "V" 200; "pete" "P" 33; "jimi" "N" 20])
```

Now I basically want to check if something like

```
"jimi" "N" x
```

is in the array. If it is, I will increment x, otherwise I'll add `"jimi" "N" 1` to the array.

The lazy way to do this would just be to iterate through the array checking all the entries, or to write my own binary search, but I am keeping the array sorted to try to minimise that cost. If there's a way I can get `searchsorted` to do this for me, that would be ideal.

It'd also be fine if I could just use `searchsorted` on `"jimi"` - my understanding is that (if that worked) it would return a range where `"jimi"` appears in the sorted array? That would be fine, the second column of the array comes from a small enough domain that I don't mind looping through that the slow way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a dictionary.  Perhaps this approach somewhat sidesteps the letter of the question, but it fits nicely with the goal of providing a collection that is easily and efficiently incremented.

```
julia> VERSION
v"0.3.5"

julia> testv = ["zebra" "N" 20; "jimi" "V" 100; "johnny" "V" 200; "pete" "P" 33; "jimi" "N" 20]
```

Make a dictionary, having keys constructed from the string pair and values that are the totals.  Note that order is not relevant to manipulating the data, but the data can be ordered easily enough for persentation

```
julia> dv = {[testv[i,1], testv[i,2]] => testv[i,3] for i in 1:size(testv)[1]}
Dict{Any,Any} with 5 entries:
  ASCIIString["zebra","N"]  => 20
  ASCIIString["pete","P"]   => 33
  ASCIIString["jimi","N"]   => 20
  ASCIIString["jimi","V"]   => 100
  ASCIIString["johnny","V"] => 200

julia> for k in sort(collect(keys(dv)), by=(x -> join(x,"")))
           println(k[1], " ", k[2], " ", dv[k])
       end
jimi N 20
jimi V 100
johnny V 200
pete P 33
zebra N 20
```

Increment the collection as you like

```
julia> k = ["mike", "S"]
julia> get!(dv, k, 0)
julia> dv[k] += 1
julia> k = ["matt", "B"]
julia> get!(dv, k, 0)
julia> dv[k] += 1
julia> k = ["jimi","N"]
julia> get!(dv, k, 0)
julia> dv[k] += 1
```

And then you have

```
julia> for k in sort(collect(keys(dv)), by=(x -> join(x,"")))
           println(k[1], " ", k[2], " ", dv[k])
       end
jimi N 21
jimi V 100
johnny V 200
matt B 1
mike S 1
pete P 33
zebra N 20
```

Of course there is a lot of polish that one could add to this, but I think that I've shown the basic approach.  If you have specific questions beyond this, I'd be glad to elaborate.

And I should tell you how to get an array of the sort that you started with:

```
julia> testv = [[k[1], k[2], dv[k]] for k in sort(collect(keys(dv)), by=(x -> join(x,"")))]

julia> testv = [i[j] for i in tv, j in 1:3]
7x3 Array{Any,2}:
 "jimi"    "N"   21
 "jimi"    "V"  100
 "johnny"  "V"  200
 "matt"    "B"    1
 "mike"    "S"    1
 "pete"    "P"   33
 "zebra"   "N"   20
```

Answer (score 2):

There aren't many functions in base julia to work with rows of a two-dimensional matrix (beyond sortrows - see the output from `apropos("rows")`).  This is partly because matrices with columns of different types don't perform very well, and partly because there are some great alternatives.  There are several options here that will probably work better for you.

### Vector of tuples

By using a vector of tuples instead of a matrix, you gain much better performance and the ability to search, grow, insert, delete, etc. It also ensures that each "row" (which is now just one element - a tuple) has the proper types.

```
julia> A = [("zebra", "N", 20), ("jimi", "V", 100), ("johnny", "V", 200), ("pete", "P", 33), ("jimi", "N", 20)];

julia> sort!(A) # Sort A in-place
5-element Array{(ASCIIString,ASCIIString,Int64),1}:
 ("jimi","N",20)
 ("jimi","V",100)
 ("johnny","V",200)
 ("pete","P",33)
 ("zebra","N",20)

julia> idxs = searchsorted(A, ("matt", "B", 100))
4:3

julia> isempty(idxs) && splice!(A, idxs, [("matt", "B", 100)])
0-element Array{(ASCIIString,ASCIIString,Int64),1}

julia> A
6-element Array{(ASCIIString,ASCIIString,Int64),1}:
 ("jimi","N",20)
 ("jimi","V",100)
 ("johnny","V",200)
 ("matt","B",100)
 ("pete","P",33)
 ("zebra","N",20)
```

### Vector of a custom type

Another option that is more appealing if you're going to be using this sort of data often is to create a custom type.  It takes a little more work to setup, but it then allows you to also create your own methods to work with this sort of data.

```
immutable MyData
    name::UTF8String
    initial::UTF8String
    score::Int
end
# We have to tell Julia how to sort these types by defining isless
function Base.isless(a::MyData, b::MyData)
    isless((a.name, a.initial, a.score), (b.name, b.initial, b.score))
end

julia> B = [MyData("zebra", "N", 20), MyData("jimi", "V", 100), MyData("johnny", "V", 200), MyData("pete", "P", 33), MyData("jimi", "N", 20)]

julia> sort!(B)
5-element Array{MyData,1}:
 MyData("jimi","N",20)
 MyData("jimi","V",100)
 MyData("johnny","V",200)
 MyData("pete","P",33)
 MyData("zebra","N",20)

julia> idxs = searchsorted(B, MyData("matt", "B", 100))
julia> isempty(idxs) && splice!(B, idxs, [MyData("matt", "B", 100)])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful, but I'm not sure it addresses the search problem I was having, namely how to search the structure (making use of the fact that it's sorted, for efficiency) using just the first one or two elements of the tuple (so rather than searching for ("matt", "B", 100) I want to search for ("matt", "B") or even just "matt", and find the range of indices of tuples beginning with that element). Is that possible with this structure?

Comment: @jfhc Matt's is a good answer, and I certainly learned some things from reading it.  I believe that he can answer the question of using only the first two elements by providing the appropriate `by` or `lt` functions for his `searchsorted` calls, something similar to what I did to get a sorted listing of the data from the dictionary.  Missing I think is a discussion of how the totals of "names" that already exist in the table are to be incremented.

Comment: Exactly.  To get all indices that match the first name "jimi" with the vector of tuples, you can use: `searchsorted(A, ("jimi",), by=x->x[1])`.  Similarly if you want to search for the second element at the same time, too: `searchsorted(A, ("jimi","V"), by=x->(x[1], x[2]))`.  And a similar solution with the custom type - just use field names instead of indices.

Comment: One of the things that I learned from this answer is the concept of passing tuples to Julia's search functions to get cascaded conditions and thus have effective tie breaking in the searches.  I puzzled over the tie breaking early on in my Julia experience (which was not that long ago) and soon realized that `by` functions allowed me to implement such cascades.  However, I had been unaware of the concept of using tuples in `by`.  This is a very elegant and easily used technique, much better than the crude, `by=(x -> join(x,""))` that I used in my answer.

Comment: Does it make sense to request that the [Sorting and Related Functions](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/sort/#sorting-and-related-functions) section of the Julia documentation mention `by=<tuple>` as a technique for implementing tie breaking in searches?  Such an addition would have been quite helpful for me, and I imagine @jfhc as well.